# java-applet gui testing with python

Tags: python

is there any frame-work or tool to test java-applets in python

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you mean or why you want to test Java in Python but Jython may be helpful.

Comment: I have a java-applet window, I want to click some buttons on that applet using python.